# How Can I retrieve SFMC Automation ObjectID using SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, automationstudio

I am trying to fetch the ObjectID of an Automation created in Salesforce Marketing Cloud using SOAP API call. So that I can use that in starting the automation using API Call from a third party system.I am using the below code to fetch the same.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <action>Retrieve</action>
                <ObjectType>Automation</ObjectType>
                <Properties>ProgramID</Properties>
                <Properties>Name</Properties>
                <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                    <Property>Name</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                    <Value>Voucher_Redemption</Value>
                </Filter>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`

But in Response, I am getting 500 error code and also the below error XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/fault
        urn:uuid:10e22599-6abe-4531-9d09-9340245d1221
        http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous
        
            
                2019-07-03T12:27:29Z
                2019-07-03T12:32:29Z
            
        
    
    
        
            
                soap:Sender
            
            **

> WSE012: The input was not a valid SOAP message because the following information is missing:
>   action.

**

Comment: Add the following header pair into your call: Name: SoapAction | Value: Retrieve.  So would look like this - SoapAction: Retrieve.

Comment: Hi @Gortonington thank you for your help now it worked....I was passing the name-value pair in the wrong place....It needed to be sent in the Header section of the call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample of a SOAP request that will return the ObjectID of an Automation

Replace `{accessToken}` with your accessToken accordingly

Replace `{NameOfAutomation}` with the exact name of your automation

Also make sure you are passing the appropriate headers as well.

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: Retrieve
```

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
    <fueloauth xmlms="http://exacttarget.com">{accessToken}</fueloauth>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>Automation</ObjectType>
            <Properties>ProgramID</Properties>
            <Properties>Name</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                <Property>Name</Property>
                <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                <Value>{NameOfAutomation}</Value>
            </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

You should get the following response which will include the ObjectID as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:3c4abac7-6d22-4784-99e9-45fbed480f69</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:6410695b-21e0-4433-8b48-101e37316fa6</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-bac127ef-8243-4831-94b8-99917b6eab96">
                <wsu:Created>2019-07-03T16:05:11Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2019-07-03T16:10:11Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>cc68d3dd-e2f7-4eef-8c4e-8821f9031b76</RequestID>
            <Results xsi:type="Automation">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID>13cb7422-0219-41e5-ab5a-8f21a410bfb0</ObjectID>
                <Name>NameOfAutomation</Name>
            </Results>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```